# How to spend 1am to 7am in NYC port authority

Tags: buses, layovers, new-york-city

I am returning home for thanksgiving and am doing so by bus.

I have bought my ticket and apparently my bus will arrive at the New York city port authority Bus terminal ( 625 8th Ave, New York, NY 10018) at 1:00am sadly. I will have my laptop bag and a over the shoulder luggage bag on me.

I could either spend money and wait in the bus terminal for another 1h or so to wait for a bus(20$) to an area close to home(rather not disclose where home is) and then pay 50$ for a taxi home, arriving at 3-4am.

OR: I could spend time in NYC from 1am until the morning buses(7~9am) run directly to my home (20$) and take a taxi home(5-10$).

I have done the first option(expensive taxi) about twice now and was wondering if there would be a cheaper, "better" way to **spend time(1am- 9am) near NYC bearing the factors of**:

-not wanting to spend over 70$(unless you justified)

-being able to bring my luggage(1 laptop bag and 1 over the shoulder bag)

-safe places?( I am a shut in(a bit of a "hikikomori"), and have only been in a bar once or twice, I have heard parks are dangerous as are dark alleyways.)

Comment: Your plan A is $70, your plan B is $25-30, your "better" way factors include less than $70.  Does this "not spend over $70" have to include plan B costs, so actually $40-45 to spend during your layover?

Comment: @Tom              It does not have to include plan B cost, so any proposed option could be stated as long as it is not greater than plan A(70$), but if it would be, then a justification/argument would be appreciated. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Though, if you _did_ mention the city you are traveling to, someone might be able to find a better option for you.

Comment: Are you in Bergen County? or West New York/Weehawken?

Comment: @MichaelHampton                 I am headed to the Orange county area, my home is 40mins away from middletown. Thats all I really want to disclose. Sorry.

Comment: Ahh, you'll just miss the last Metro-North out of Penn Station at 12:30 am too, and they don't start departing again until 8:20 am.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Last time I was in NYC overnight waiting for an early morning bus out of Port Authority, I spent a few hours in the [Starbucks on 42nd Street](https://goo.gl/maps/eKzXomTpWcH2) east of 8th Avenue. You can see it from the Port Authority terminal's main entrance on 8th.

The bad news is that it's no longer open 24 hours.

The good news is that there's another [Starbucks at 43rd and Broadway](https://goo.gl/maps/ir6hqrVkbWy) that *is* open 24 hours. This is the part of Times Square that you see on TV. Spend a few hours drinking coffee and surfing the net on the free Wi-Fi. This will be about a five minute walk from Port Authority.

(And regular coffee refills are still 50 cents, or free if you have a registered [Starbucks card](http://customerservice.starbucks.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1882).)

To get to Times Square, walk out the doors of Port Authority, (at that time of night the 42nd Street entrance is closed; you will come out on the 8th Avenue entrance) **ignore anyone who attempts to speak to you at the doors of the building** (unless it's obviously NYPD or MTA), then walk the same direction you are facing, down 42nd Street to 7th Avenue and turn left.

This is very unlikely to cost you more than $70.

Comment: Do Starbucks mind people with bags though? I dont want to be a burden.

Comment: No, they don't care, it's common enough. Especially since it's a big tourist area. And it shouldn't be too busy at that time of night.

Comment: Michael, what's the reason behind the warning in bold? Is that area known for crime, etc?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Not that much crime, but you do have a lot of "professional" panhandlers and the like.

Comment: So panhandlers are a threat?